# Postgres Proper usage of Group by in a Inner Join Statement

Tags: database, postgresql, group-by

**EDIT** I updated my question with a SQL Fiddle Sample http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8d88b/1

I'm currently making a report from a database records but I don't know how my query should look like, first of all I have 2 tables. Application Forms, and a table for Login Hours of each user

```
forms
->id
->agent_id
->SomeInfo
->created_at


loginhours
->id
->user_id
->loginhours (decimal)
->created_at
```

And I have report with the following columns

```
UserID, TotalLoginHours, TotalApplication, Application Per Hour (aph), Revenue Per Hour (rph)
```

So right now I have this query

```
SELECT a.agent_id, SUM(b.loginhours) as TotalLoginHours, COUNT(a.id) as TotalApplication, SUM(b.loginhours) / COUNT(a.id) as ApplicationPerHour,   (SUM(b.loginhours) / COUNT(a.id)) * 1.75 as RPH 
FROM forms a 
INNER JOIN loginhours b ON a.agent_id = b.user_id WHERE a.created_at = '2015-07-17' 
GROUP BY a.agent_id
```

Note that `user_id` and `agent_id` is the same.

I want to get the result based on the date selected, example `2015-07-17` I got results but my problem is the `loginhours` is being `SUM` based on the number of application for each user. So for example the `user1` has 2 records on `forms` table and his `loginhours` from `2015-07-17` is `2` then in my result the `loginhours` becomes `4` which is wrong, I think it is on my `GROUP BY` statement. Can you help me how to properly query this?
Thanks

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: Hi. Thanks . I updated it with an sql fiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a good practice but somehow I figured it out with

```
SELECT a.agent_id
 ,(SELECT SUM(loginhours) 
   FROM loginhours 
   WHERE user_id = a.agent_id 
     AND created_at = '2015-07-17' 
   GROUP BY created_at) as TotalLoginHours
 ,COUNT(a.id) as TotalApplication
 ,(SELECT SUM(loginhours) 
   FROM loginhours 
   WHERE user_id = a.agent_id 
     AND created_at = '2015-07-17' 
   GROUP BY created_at) / COUNT(a.id) as ApplicationPerHour
 ,((SELECT SUM(loginhours) 
    FROM loginhours 
    WHERE user_id = a.agent_id 
      AND created_at = '2015-07-17' 
    GROUP BY created_at) / COUNT(a.id)) * 1.75 as RPH 
FROM forms a 
INNER JOIN loginhours b 
   ON a.agent_id = b.user_id 
WHERE a.created_at = '2015-07-17' 
GROUP BY a.agent_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, loginhours, applications, 
loginhours/applications as applications_per_hour, 
loginhours/applications * 1.75 as rph
FROM 
(
  SELECT user_id, SUM(loginhours) as loginhours
  FROM loginhours
  WHERE created_at = '2015-07-17' 
  GROUP BY user_id
)hours
JOIN 
(
  SELECT agent_id, COUNT(DISTINCT id) as applications
  FROM forms
  WHERE created_at = '2015-07-17' 
  GROUP BY agent_id
)applications
ON hours.user_id = applications.agent_id
```